# Dispalying the result of different tables using tabs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I want some suggestions regarding this topic. I have different types of tables. What I want is whenever mysql returns results from multiple tables it gets displayed according to table's name. Also I am using pagination so that if one table returns more than 10 results the results get displayed on multiple pages. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Comment: are u planning to use any third party tools like kendo or bootstrap?

Comment: use hibernate pagination.`setMaxResults`

Comment: @ManoharR.A No, I just want to use pure php and jquery.

Comment: u will have to create some kind of a template wiht ur tabular data and load it for every item in yor result